Java Test command running but no test found error
Using notepad, i am running this test below, but it compiles and ran successfully but there will be no test found
This is the test file below :
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;


public class CreditCardValidationTest{

    @Test
    public void CheckCreditCardValidationTest(){


    String creditCardNumber = "9871238967321063";

    CreditCardValidation tester = new CreditCardValidation();

    boolean output = tester.checkCreditCardValidation(creditCardNumber);

    assertTrue(output);

}

}
This is the output I got after I ran the test  .
After running the test on Git Bash, there is failed or successful test, please I need help to rectify the issue. Thank you

You tell JUnit to search for tests in CreditCardValidation, but there are no tests in CreditCardValidation - the tests are in CreditCardValidationTest. You need to run your tests with --include-classname CreditCardValidationTest

You can try to pass name of your test to it. Instead of name of tested class.
